# How to get data from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Can you help me with this? I  have to make a query to get data from different tables using inner join.

Here's my query:

```
select 
    a.DocEntry,
    a.CardName,
    a.Address,
    a.Address2, 
    a.CardCode,
    a.TaxDate,
    b.Dscription, 
    b.Quantity,
    b.Price,
    b.GTotal,
    b.WhsCode,
    c.WhsName,
    d.CompnyName, 
    d.CompnyAddr, 
    d.Phone1,
    e.U_NAME
from OPOR a 
        inner join POR1 b on a.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
        inner join OWHS c on a.DocEntry = c.WhsCode
        inner join OADM d on a.DocEntry = d.CompnyName
        inner join OUSR e on a.DocEntry = e.U_NAME
where b.DocEntry = 36
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'OEC Computers UK' to data type int.

Comment: These, `inner join OADM d on a.DocEntry = d.CompnyName
        inner join OUSR e on a.DocEntry = e.U_NAME` look like they might be comparing numbers to strings.

Comment: please show me data type of  OPOR .DocEntry, OWHS.Whscode, OADM.CompnyName and OUSR.U_Name

Answer (score 0):

You are compairing a `NVarchar` column to an `int` value or column.
The exception you provided  is thrown if this column contains at least one value that cannot be converted. *(values cannot be parsed implicitly by sql server)*

Check this part of your query, it looks like a join is made on a varchar column and an integer column

```
inner join OADM d on a.DocEntry = d.CompnyName
inner join OUSR e on a.DocEntry = e.U_NAME
```

If it is necessary -*(this is not recommended)* - to make a similar join you have to cast the `int` column as `nvarchar` ex:

```
inner join OUSR e on CAST(a.DocEntry AS NVARCHAR(255)) = e.U_NAME
```

**And Also**

If the datatype of `DocEntry` is `NVarchar` the exception may be thrown by

```
b.DocEntry = 36
```

So you have to use instead of it

```
b.DocEntry = '36'
```

Answer (score -1):

What type of columns "DocEntry","WhsCode","CompnyName","U_NAME"?

There is "OEC Computers UK" that cant convert to integer.

That column's data must be number, or you cant compare it.

Comment: These questions should be comments, and your reputation is high enough to do that, even after my downvote.